# What can be the efficient approach to solve the 8 puzzle problem?

Tags: algorithm, logic, puzzle, a-star, sliding-tile-puzzle

The 8-puzzle is a square board with 9 positions, filled by 8 numbered tiles and one gap. At any point, a tile adjacent to the gap can be moved into the gap, creating a new gap position. In other words the gap can be swapped with an adjacent (horizontally and vertically) tile. The objective in the game is to begin with an arbitrary configuration of tiles, and move them so as to get the numbered tiles arranged in ascending order either running around the perimeter of the board or ordered from left to right, with 1 in the top left-hand position.

[image: 8 puzzle]

I was wondering what approach will be efficient to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not convinced that there is always a solution. Supposedly Erno Rubik (inventor of the Rubik’s cube) sold a 15-puzzle (4x4 grid) with the numbers 1 – 15, with numbers 14 and 15 swapped . He offered a substantial reward for those who could solve it. He, of course, knew it was impossible.

Comment: Are you reading http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Sliding-Around.aspx by any chance?

Comment: @Eric - Well, yes, it may be impossible if numbers were randomly pulled out and placed back in because it's moving in a way not possible in the solution.  But, if the numbers were in order and then just mixed up (AKA, shifted around), then it is possible to "work backward" to solve the problem.  I'm assuming this is a safe assumption to make here.

I am curious, too, if there's an efficient solution.

Comment: Exactly half of all possible configurations have a solution.  In effect, you can calculate a parity value that produces a zero or one for all configurations and simultaneously is preserved by all legal changes to the game board; half of all configurations have each parity value, and therefore configurations in one half cannot be changed to reach configurations in the other half.  I don't have time to look up the details right now, though.

You can always change between the two parity values by swapping two non-blank cells.

Comment: @eric legend has it that when sam loyd went to patent the 15 puzzle, the patent officer asked if it was solvable. when loyd admitted it was not, the officer said that in that case there could be no "working model", and hence no patent.

Comment: Thanks for that question, I had fun learning about A* and implementing in Python to see how it goes.

Comment: No voyager.I am not reading that.

(But I'll definitely have a look at it)

Comment: It is possible to check if puzzle is unsolvable by hand and counting the permutations. I once saw the example of this problem in mathetamics mazaine for high scholl.

Comment: @Eric It was Sam Loyd, not Erno Rubik.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I will just attempt to rewrite the previous answer with more details on why it is optimal.

The A* algorithm taken directly from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) is

```
            function A*(start,goal)
                    closedset := the empty set                 // The set of nodes already evaluated.     
                    openset := set containing the initial node // The set of tentative nodes to be evaluated.
                    came_from := the empty map                 // The map of navigated nodes.
                    g_score[start] := 0                        // Distance from start along optimal path.
            h_score[start] := heuristic_estimate_of_distance(start, goal)
                    f_score[start] := h_score[start]           // Estimated total distance from start to goal through y.
                    while openset is not empty
                    x := the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value
                    if x = goal
            return reconstruct_path(came_from, came_from[goal])
                    remove x from openset
                    add x to closedset
            foreach y in neighbor_nodes(x)
                    if y in closedset
                    continue
            tentative_g_score := g_score[x] + dist_between(x,y)

                    if y not in openset
                    add y to openset
                    tentative_is_better := true
                    elseif tentative_g_score < g_score[y]
                    tentative_is_better := true
                    else
                    tentative_is_better := false
                    if tentative_is_better = true
                    came_from[y] := x
                    g_score[y] := tentative_g_score
            h_score[y] := heuristic_estimate_of_distance(y, goal)
                    f_score[y] := g_score[y] + h_score[y]
                    return failure

            function reconstruct_path(came_from, current_node)
                    if came_from[current_node] is set
                    p = reconstruct_path(came_from, came_from[current_node])
            return (p + current_node)
                    else
                    return current_node
```

So let me fill in all the details here.

`heuristic_estimate_of_distance` is the function Σ d(x<sub>i</sub>) where d(.) is the Manhattan distance of each square x<sub>i</sub> from its goal state.

So the setup

```
            1 2 3
            4 7 6
            8 5
```

would have a `heuristic_estimate_of_distance` of 1+2+1=4 since each of 8,5 are one away from their goal position with d(.)=1 and 7 is 2 away from its goal state with d(7)=2.

The set of nodes that the A* searches over is defined to be the starting position followed by all possible legal positions. That is lets say the starting position `x` is as above:

```
            x =
            1 2 3
            4 7 6
            8 5
```

then the function `neighbor_nodes(x)` produces the 2 possible legal moves:

```
            1 2 3
            4 7 
            8 5 6

            or

            1 2 3
            4 7 6
            8   5
```

The function `dist_between(x,y)` is defined as the number of square moves that took place to transition from state `x` to `y`. This is mostly going to be equal to 1 in A* always for the purposes of your algorithm.

`closedset` and `openset` are both specific to the A* algorithm and can be implemented using standard data structures (priority queues I believe.) `came_from` is a data structure used
to reconstruct the solution found using the function `reconstruct_path` who's details can be found on wikipedia. If you do not wish to remember the solution you do not need to implement this.

Last, I will address the issue of optimality. Consider the excerpt from the A* wikipedia article:

"If the heuristic function h is admissible, meaning that it never overestimates the actual minimal cost of reaching the goal, then A* is itself admissible (or optimal) if we do not use a closed set. If a closed set is used, then h must also be monotonic (or consistent) for A* to be optimal. This means that for any pair of adjacent nodes x and y, where d(x,y) denotes the length of the edge between them, we must have:
h(x) <= d(x,y) +h(y)"

So it suffices to show that our heuristic is admissible and monotonic. For the former (admissibility), note that given any configuration our heuristic (sum of all distances) estimates that each square is not constrained by only legal moves and can move freely towards its goal position, which is clearly an optimistic estimate, hence our heuristic is admissible (or it never over-estimates since reaching a goal position will always take *at least* as many moves as the heuristic estimates.)

The monotonicity requirement stated in words is:
"The heuristic cost (estimated distance to goal state) of any node must be less than or equal to the cost of transitioning to any adjacent node plus the heuristic cost of that node."

It is mainly to prevent the possibility of negative cycles, where transitioning to an unrelated node may decrease the distance to the goal node more than the cost of actually making the transition, suggesting a poor heuristic.

To show monotonicity its pretty simple in our case. Any adjacent nodes x,y have d(x,y)=1 by our definition of d. Thus we need to show

h(x) <= h(y) + 1

which is equivalent to

h(x) - h(y) <= 1

which is equivalent to

Σ d(x<sub>i</sub>) - Σ d(y<sub>i</sub>) <= 1

which is equivalent to

Σ d(x<sub>i</sub>) - d(y<sub>i</sub>) <= 1

We know by our definition of `neighbor_nodes(x)` that two neighbour nodes x,y can have at most the position of one square differing, meaning that in our sums the term

d(x<sub>i</sub>) - d(y<sub>i</sub>) = 0

for all but 1 value of i. Lets say without loss of generality this is true of i=k. Furthermore, we know that for i=k, the node has moved at most one place, so its distance to 
a goal state must be at most one more than in the previous state thus:

Σ d(x<sub>i</sub>) - d(y<sub>i</sub>) = d(x<sub>k</sub>) - d(y<sub>k</sub>) <= 1

showing monotonicity. This shows what needed to be showed, thus proving this algorithm will be optimal (in a big-O notation or asymptotic kind of way.)

Note, that I have shown optimality in terms of big-O notation but there is still lots of room to play in terms of tweaking the heuristic. You can add additional twists to it so that it is a closer estimate of the actual distance to the goal state, *however* you have to make *sure* that the heuristic is always an *underestimate* otherwise you loose optimality!

### EDIT MANY MOONS LATER

Reading this over again (much) later, I realized the way I wrote it sort of confounds the meaning of optimality of this algorithm.

There are two distinct meanings of optimality I was trying to get at here:

1) The algorithm produces an optimal solution, that is the best possible solution given the objective criteria.

2) The algorithm expands the least number of state nodes of all possible algorithms using the same heuristic.

The simplest way to understand why you need admissibility and monotonicity of the heuristic to obtain 1) is to view A* as an application of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm on a graph where the edge weights are given by the node distance traveled thus far plus the heuristic distance. Without these two properties, we would have negative edges in the graph, thereby negative cycles would be possible and Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm would no longer return the correct answer! (Construct a simple example of this to convince yourself.)

2) is actually quite confusing to understand. To fully understand the meaning of this, there are a lot of quantifiers on this statement, such as when talking about other algorithms, one refers to `similar` algorithms as A* that expand nodes and search without a-priori information (other than the heuristic.) Obviously, one can construct a trivial counter-example otherwise, such as an oracle or genie that tells you the answer at every step of the way. To understand this statement in depth I highly suggest reading the last paragraph in the History section on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#History) as well as looking into all the citations and footnotes in that carefully stated sentence.

I hope this clears up any remaining confusion among would-be readers.

Comment: I should add that A* is really only optimal if you have no specialized knowledge to take into account to solve your actual problem. It's still exponentially bounded in runtime and space which is pretty aweful, but for small problems it works.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the heuristic that is based on the positions of the numbers, that is the higher the overall sum of all the distances of each letter from its goal state is, the higher the heuristic value. Then you can implement A* search which can be proved to be the optimal search in terms of time and space complexity (provided the heuristic is monotonic and admissible.) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: Yup, A* is much more suitable for this problem than IDDFS. IDDFS is about as fast as A* without any heuristic. But even the most simple heuristics improve the algorithm a lot.

Comment: @Accipitridae, IDDFS is not as fast as A* without any heuristic. It visits most nodes more than once whereas A* without heuristic only still visits nodes once and once only.

Comment: The way this answer is worded gives a strong impression that it produces the best answer in the best possible way. But it doesn't even attempt to make any kind of argument that the heuristic is suitable.

Comment: Sum of the distances is good enough heuristics. Even better one would take into account the observation that numbers that are adjacent in final solution should be coupled together as the game progress (with empty square behaving as if all adjacent to it are adjacent to each other). And all other things being equal the empty square should stay out of the edge during search.

Comment: @ Jason Orendorff: that's because this does produce the best possible answer in terms of big-O notation (asymptotic behavior.) You can go ahead and experiment with heuristics that would further reduce the run time (by constant factors) but it remains that you will not be able to produce a better asymptotic time.

Answer (score 6):

Since the OP cannot post a picture, this is what he's talking about:

[image: 8 Puzzle - Initial State]

As far as solving this puzzle, goes, take a look at the [iterative deepening depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) algorithm, as made relevant to the 8-puzzle problem by [this page](http://www.8puzzle.com/8_puzzle_algorithm.html).

Answer (score 4):

Donut's got it! IDDFS will do the trick, considering the relatively limited search space of this puzzle.  It would be efficient hence respond to the OP's question.  It would find the optimal solution, but not necessarily in optimal complexity.

Implementing IDDFS would be the more complicated part of this problem, I just want to suggest an simple approach to managing the board, the games rules etc.  This in particular addresses a way to obtain initial states for the puzzle which are solvable.  An hinted in the notes of the question, not all random assignemts of 9 tites (considering the empty slot a special tile), will yield a solvable puzzle.  It is a matter of mathematical parity...    So, here's a suggestions to model the game:

Make the list of all 3x3 permutation matrices which represent valid "moves" of the game.
Such list is a subset of 3x3s w/ all zeros and two ones.  Each matrix gets an ID which will be quite convenient to keep track of the moves, in the IDDFS search tree.   An alternative to matrices, is to have two-tuples of the tile position numbers to swap, this may lead to faster implementation.

Such matrices can be used to create the initial puzzle state, starting with the "win" state, and running a arbitrary number of permutations selected at random.  In addition to ensuring that the initial state is solvable this approach also provides a *indicative* number of moves with which a given puzzle can be solved.

Now let's just implement the IDDFS algo and [joke]return the assignement for an A+[/joke]...

Comment: Was the [joke] a subtle pun on A*? Haha :)

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of the classical shortest path algorithm. You can read more about shortest path [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

In short, think of all possible states of the puzzle as of vertices in some graph. With each move you change states - so, each valid move represents an edge of the graph. Since moves don't have any cost, you may think of the cost of each move being 1. The following c++-like pseudo-code will work for this problem:

```
{
int[][] field = new int[3][3];
//  fill the input here
map<string, int> path;
queue<string> q;
put(field, 0); // we can get to the starting position in 0 turns
while (!q.empty()) {
    string v = q.poll();
    int[][] take = decode(v); 
    int time = path.get(v);
    if (isFinalPosition(take)) {
        return time;
    }
    for each valid move from take to int[][] newPosition {
        put(newPosition, time + 1);
    }
}
// no path
return -1;
}

void isFinalPosition(int[][] q) {
    return encode(q) == "123456780"; // 0 represents empty space
}
void put(int[][] position, int time) {
    string s = encode(newPosition);
    if (!path.contains(s)) {
        path.put(s, time);
    }
}

string encode(int[][] field) {
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) s += field[i][j];
    return s;
}

int[][] decode(string s) {
    int[][] ans = new int[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) field[i][j] = s[i * 3 + j];
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: it can be shown that if A* search satisfies certain constraints, then it is  equivalent to finding the shortest path ;) using dijkstra's algorithm

Answer (score 2):

See this link for my  [*parallel* iterative deepening search for a solution to the 15-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862599/multithreading-puzzles/1866161#1866161), which is the 4x4 big-brother of the 8-puzzle.

Comment: parallel algorithms break the mold in the sense that they may outperform A* asymptotically due to the availability of extra processors.