# Solving 8 puzzle with Best-First Search in Prolog

Tags: function, search, prolog, heuristics, sliding-tile-puzzle

as the title says, I have to make a prolog progam that solves the 8 puzzle using best-first search, I'm new to Prolog and A. I. so I'm having a hard time.

For now what I have is the move rules:

```
%% move left in the top row
move([X1,0,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [0,X1,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9]).
move([X1,X2,0, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,0,X2, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9]).

%% move left in the middle row
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,0,X6,X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, 0,X4,X6,X7,X8,X9]).
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,0,X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, X4,0,X5,X7,X8,X9]).

%% move left in the bottom row
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,0,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6, 0,X7,X9]).
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,0],
     [X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,0,X8]).

%% move right in the top row 
    move([0,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X2,0,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9]).
move([X1,0,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X3,0, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9]).

%% move right in the middle row 
move([X1,X2,X3, 0,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, X5,0,X6, X7,X8,X9]).
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,0,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, X4,X6,0, X7,X8,X9]).

%% move right in the bottom row
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6,0,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6,X8,0,X9]).
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6,X7,0,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6,X7,X9,0]).

%% move up from the middle row
move([X1,X2,X3, 0,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [0,X2,X3, X1,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9]).
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,0,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,0,X3, X4,X2,X6, X7,X8,X9]).
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,0, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,0, X4,X5,X3, X7,X8,X9]).

%% move up from the bottom row
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,0,X9],
 [X1,X2,X3, X4,0,X6, X7,X5,X9]).
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,0],
     [X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,0, X7,X8,X6]).
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6, 0,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, 0,X5,X6, X4,X8,X9]).

%% move down from the top row
move([0,X2,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X4,X2,X3, 0,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9]).
move([X1,0,X3, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X5,X3, X4,0,X6, X7,X8,X9]).
move([X1,X2,0, X4,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,X6, X4,X5,0, X7,X8,X9]).

%% move down from the middle row
move([X1,X2,X3, 0,X5,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, X7,X5,X6, 0,X8,X9]).
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,0,X6, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, X4,X8,X6, X7,0,X9]).
move([X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,0, X7,X8,X9],
     [X1,X2,X3, X4,X5,X9, X7,X8,0]).
```

(I know there is an easier way using lists, but this is what has worked for me)

And the best first code I found on the internet: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~luger/ai-final/code/PROLOG.best.html

But on that best first code there is this heuristic function that doesn't run:

```
go(Start, Goal) :- 
   empty_set(Closed),
   empty_sort_queue(Empty_open),
   heuristic(Start, Goal, H),
   state_record(Start, nil, 0, H, H, First_record),
   insert_sort_queue(First_record, Empty_open, Open),
   path(Open,Closed, Goal).
```

I assume because it isn't defined anywhere and I need to define it myself, since heuristics change depending on the problem.

So I tought of using the "tiles out of place" heuristic for the 8 puzzle, since it sounds easier to code than manhattan distance or whatever. But now I'm stuck on how to program that, I googled everywhere on how to compare lists and how to add variables and I kinda made this, which I don't know if would work:

```
heuristic([],[],H).
heuristic([Head1|Tail1],[Head2|Tail2], H):-
   not(samePlace(Head1,Head2))->H1 is H + 1,
   heuristic(Tail1, Tail2, H1).
```

My idea is that it searches every element of the start list and compares it to the goal list and then if they're different it adds 1 to H, being H the number of tiles out of place.

For what I also defined the "tiles in the same place rules":

```
samePlace([X,_,_,_,_,_,_],[X,_,_,_,_,_,_]).
samePlace([_,X,_,_,_,_,_],[_,X,_,_,_,_,_]). 
samePlace([_,_,X,_,_,_,_],[_,_,X,_,_,_,_]).
samePlace([_,_,_,X,_,_,_],[_,_,_,X,_,_,_]).
samePlace([_,_,_,_,X,_,_],[_,_,_,_,X,_,_]).
samePlace([_,_,_,_,_,X,_],[_,_,_,_,_,X,_]).
samePlace([_,_,_,_,_,_,X],[_,_,_,_,_,_,X]). 
(etc...)
```

But of course I get an "ERROR: heuristic/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated" which I assume it means I never initialized H.

I have no idea how the rest of the code actually works, tho I know that the best first algorythm is like the breadth first but it sorts the queue accordint to the heuristic instead of just adding to it.

My questions are:
 - Am I on the right track, or did I totally missread what that "heuristic" function in there means?
 - How can I initialize H?
 - Is my "heuristic" function code syntactically correct?

Sorry for the long post, but the rules do say I should give plenty of information.
I hope you can help me with this, any help is appreciated, so if you know any other ways of doing this feel free to post them, I'm a noob.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395513/what-can-be-the-efficient-approach-to-solve-the-8-puzzle-problem), you'll find many suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([->](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=send_arrow/2))/2 in Prolog has been introduced to make easy modelling if..then..else.. logic, but has an important difference from imperative languages: without the 'else' branch it fails when the condition fails.

Now you miss the else branch in heuristic/3. This could be intended, but I think that if samePlace(Head1,Head2) is true somewhere, this will fail to return a value, thus starting backtracking in calling code. In my experience, this is often the cause for subsequent weird error messages, like that you're reporting.

Another problem is that you fail to 'return' the value even when the predicate succeeds: try instead

```
heuristic([],[],0).
heuristic([Head1|Tail1],[Head2|Tail2], H):-
   heuristic(Tail1, Tail2, H1),
   (   not(samePlace(Head1,Head2))
   ->  H is H1 + 1
   ;   H is H1
   ).
```